# while doing pagination new data has been added to tableview that time tableview scroll is jumping in IOS swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, pagination

```
 var cellHeights: [IndexPath : CGFloat] = [:]

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    guard let height = cellHeights[indexPath] else { return 260.0 }
    return height
 }

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    cellHeights[indexPath] = cell.frame.size.height
    let lastCell = self.ScrollArray.count - 3
    if IsLastMessage == 0 {
        if indexPath.row == lastCell {
            IsPageNo = IsPageNo + 1
            UpdateScrollAPI()
        }
    }
 }
```

i have tried above code but i didn't get the solution, please any one help me out of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi see below is how I did it. Works fine.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: strCellId, for: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

        if indexPath.row == arrModel.count - 1 && pageNo != -1
        {
            // this is last cell
            self.loadMoreData(withLoader: true)
        }
        return cell
    }
```

When call API for load more data, PageNo can be managed like this:

```
if arrData.count < Int(rowsPerPage)!
{
    pageNo = -1
}
else
{
    pageNo += 1
}
```

Comment: There is no issue in pagination while adding new data to the list in tableview when I reload the tableview that time Tableview is scrolling happens ... that is issue please help me out of it.